# WordPress Database Images Location?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am working on extracting data from a WordPress database to my own.

I have managed to transfer all the comments from the `wp_comments` table into my own (`reviews`).

Each comment should have an image or attachment associated with it that the user has uploaded along with the comment, but I can't find a reference to it anywhere?

Here's a few examples of the WordPress tables, my own tables & a bit more info linking them all together.

My Table (`reviews`):

```
postid: 332
username: Lois
message: My comment
img: 
date: 2015-10-10 17:57:33
uid: NULL
commentid: 49
```

As you can see here, we have a postid (the `id` of the page the comment is on), a username, message, etc etc THEN we have a `commentid` of 49, which is the **unique ID** of that comment (these have all been kept the same when extracting them from the `wp_comments` table) - but we still don't have any image data (`img`).

Now here is the problem, there wasn't ANY image data stored in `wp_comments`, so I decided to check in `wp_commentmeta` (the most logical place to check first) - and so I searched for the **unique ID** of **49** in `wp_commentmeta`, here's what I found:

```
meta_id: 312
comment_id: 49
meta_key: rating
meta_value: 5

----------

meta_id: 309
comment_id: 49
meta_key: akismet_result
meta_value: false

----------

meta_id: 310
comment_id: 49
meta_key: akismet_history
meta_value: a:3:{s:4:"time";d:1444496314.1759700775146484375;s:5:"event";s:9:"check-ham";s:4:"user";s:4:"Lois";}
```

These are the only values associated with a comment ID of 49? I can't find images to link up with the comments anywhere!!

I checked with other comment ID's and it is the same story.

Anyone with WordPress database knowledge know where to find images that are associated with comments (user uploads)?

EDIT (**more info**): I forgot to mention, I have already looked in the `wp_posts` table, even though it does contain image data/url's none of the rows seem to match up with a valid `commentid` from the `reviews` table? (When `wp_posts` and `reviews` do share the same id, it's just a coincidence and they aren't the correct images for the comment)

Thanks

Comment: Are the images named after their ID? Eg. `310.png`? Otherwise I'd look at the image URL, make an SQL dump and simply search said SQL dump for your image filename.

Comment: I don't think that WordPress allows attachments in comments without a specific plugin. If you are using a plugin for that, which one is it?

Comment: I have no idea what plugin, it was another guy who created the WordPress site so I don't  have access to anything anymore apart from the database. Regarding image file names I will check that now, thanks